# Getting variable from socket.io in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, socket.io, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

Basically i have two sources of data, one is real time data from socket.io and other is json object. And i'm using both in front-end but the problem is that i need to pass a variable from socket.io to json parser:

This controller for my view:

```
.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope','socket','currentData', function($scope, socket,         currentData){

    // It's updated every 2 seconds
    socket.on('chnl', function(data){
         // Passed to view OK
         $scope.realtimeData = data;

         // And i need to pass this to currentData.
         $scope.foo = data.foo;
    });

    // Here i'm getting json response from factory which is computed based on socket.io foo variable and then passed to view. 
    currentData.get().then(function(data){
         if($scope.foo)...
         ...
         $scope..
    });


}]
```

The problem is anything i tried i ended up calling json object on every incoming socket.io package, what i need to calc this at it's initalization and pass data to the view.

Any solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need for it to run only once for initialization...

Move the call to the JSON service into the `.on` callback. Place it inside of a conditional which runs only when an initialization variable is set to `false`. Once the data is set, switch that variable to `true` so that it doesn't run again:

```
.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope','socket','currentData', function($scope, socket, currentData){
    $scope.fooInit = false;

    socket.on('chnl', function(data){
        $scope.realtimeData = data;
        $scope.foo = data.foo;

        if (!$scope.fooInit) {
            currentData.get().then(function(data){
                if($scope.foo)...
                 ...
                $scope..
            });
            $scope.fooInit = true;
        }
    });
}])
```